# How do apps like Pizza Hut generate all nearby Pizza Hut locations using Google Maps?

Tags: java, android, google-places-api

I am fairly new to programming and am currently working on my first full app by myself. The app has a few different parts, and one of those parts helps narrow a user's food selection down by restaurant. For instance, if the user decided they wanted to eat at Pizza Hut, my idea is that my app would generate a Google Map and using Google API, show the user all nearby pizza huts. I would also like the user to be able to click on the pizza hut icons and then it would direct them to Google Maps for directions.

Currently I am able to populate Google Maps, ask the user for permission to find their location, as well as I implemented Google Place Picker. The Google Place Picker works a bit differently than I first imagined though.

What I'm stuck on is how do I actually get just the Pizza Hut locations to populate as opposed to everything else as well?

Thank you!

Comment: The Pizza Hut parent company knows the addresses of all Pizza Hut franchises. Whether they bake that list into the app or download it from the Internet would be up to the developers of that app.

Comment: Is there a way to specify in my app to only populate Pizza Hut's information on my map? Similar to if I were to search for Pizza Hut using regular google maps? @CommonsWare

Comment: I do not know a legitimate source where you can license a copy of the geographic coordinates of all of the Pizza Hut franchises.

Comment: @CommonsWare You probably just need to open a franchise. I bet you could do it for 10 million!

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I must be misunderstanding how google places API works? Currently my map is populating all restaurants and places, including pizza hut. All I'm trying to do is have the map not show the other places but continue showing all the pizza hut locations that it already is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete) is what you want.

Send a request to: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/output?parameters`

For example: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=pizza+hut&types=geocode&language=en&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

You can also specify the [lat/lang and raidus](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/get-api-key#specify_a_key_in_your_request) in the url.

You'll need an API key. More on that [here](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/get-api-key).